# IOS: ARC methods of allocation object

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting

In my app I'm using ARC and I'm new in it.
I have two simply questions.

First question;
If I should alloc an NSArray I do

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]init];
```

but can I do also in this way?

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray array];
```

is it the same?

Second question:
if I have this:

```
UINavigationController *navigationcontroller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewC];
```

what's the version for ARC or I can write in this way?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, `[NSArray array]` will be calling `[[NSArray alloc] init]` so in an environment where ARC is being used, it makes no difference.

For the sake of completeness, there's also a third way: `[NSArray new]` is the equivalent of `[[NSArray alloc] init]`.

As for the second question, `-initWithRootViewController:` is a convenience method. It's the equivalent of doing this:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
navigationController.viewControllers = @[ rootViewController ];
```

Comment: and if I want release an NSArray? Can I do simply array = nil;? or ARC think to do that?

Comment: You can either explicitly set it to nil or wait for ARC to release it when the object moves out of scope. The standard convention is to let ARC handle releasing it. This also has the benefit of your code not being littered with "obj = nil".

Answer (score 0):

You can write these in this way, In ARC you do not have to add retain , release manually. It is done by ARC. Rest of thing you can do as.

Comment: but for alloc navigationcontroller is there only this way? Is there a new way to instance a new uinavigationcontroller?